# Unable to import mysql database in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

I have created a database named `testdb` in DigitalOcean. I have a local database file named `testdb.sql`. I need to import the data inside the local database file into DigitalOcean.

Here is what I have tried:

1) Using Filezilla I have imported `testdb.sql` into `var/www/html/database` folder.

2) I tried importing the records using below commands. But none of them worked.

**Procedure 1:**

```
mysql -u root -p testdb < /var/www/html/database/testdb.sql
```

**Procedure 2:**

```
>shell: mysql -u root -p
>mysql: use testdb;
>mysql: source /var/www/html/database/testdb.sql;
```

The cursor just exits but doesn't import data after both the procedures. What am I missing here?

Comment: what is the size of .sql file?

Comment: @ReyanChougle around 11 MB

Comment: make sure your file is not compressed

Comment: Its not compressed